# Upgrade NopCommerce Site

Tags: nopcommerce, nopcommerce-3.90, nopcommerce-4.0

I am trying to upgrade a Nop site on the server.  I think it was installed using the Web Platform installer.  Whether I use the "No Source" option or I use the Web source code option and deploy / publish, I don't end up with a folder that reflects what is currently on the server AT ALL.  My next option is to just install a separate web, go through the install process and copy the files over.  The DB upgrade is a no brainer, since it is just an upgrade script.  I am obviously missing something.... or not had enough coffee....

[image: What is currently on the server "IIS" allocated Folder]

Comment: The reason for the different folder structure of 3.9 and 4.0 is the .net framework. 4.0 has moved on ASP.NET Core 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the different folder structure of 3.9 and 4.0 is the .net framework. 4.0 is using ASP.NET Core 2.0.

---

Folder Structure 3.9 -> 4.0

- Administration >> Areas/Admin
- App_Data >> App_Data
- bin >> all binaries are now in app root
- Content >> wwwroot
- Plugins >> Plugins
- Scripts >> wwwroot
- Themes >> Themes
- Views >> Views

Keep in mind, you cannot use plugins & themes of 3.9 in 4.0 without migrating them.

Comment: Does that mean that creating a new site and migrating the DB/Files is a better option than trying to upgrade an existing site?

Comment: Does the existing 3.9 site have any modifications? Are there any plugins/themes used, if so, do they have a 4.0 version?

Comment: No modifications, just a few payment plugins.  It is running 3.9 and I plan to go to 4.0.

Comment: So then it should be no problem to upgrade to 4.0. Most plugin providers already have their 4.0 version published.